# CROSS JOIN and updatable model design for Ruby on Rails

Tags: database-design, schema

I am trying to build the multi-level model in rub on rails to allow the following to happen: When a user creates a campaign they will select some categories and some metros from tables Category and Metro. Those selections will then be placed within two tables as campaign_category and campaign_metro. But upon the creation of those entries I wish for then another table to be populated with the permutation of those combinations within that table or a series of tables to allow for linking the campaign, the category and metros selected for a user to set a bid price on.

For example say a user creates a campaign that has id 10 and selects category with id 1 and 2, and metros with id 3 and 4. In the tables campaign_category appears:

[image]

and in table campaign_metro appears:

[image]

How can I allow for the third level table (or series of tables) to be populated with the total permutations of selected category and metro upon the creation of a campaign and also work with ruby on rails active record constructs?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: @ypercube I am trying to keep it open ended. In my last question I suggested the table schema that I thought would work, but ended up being too constricting and a terrible design (with the three foreign keys) to work simply in rails